# Get variable dynamically

Tags: dynamic, groovy

Is there any way to reference variables dynamically like methods?  [Here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy) is the Groovy example of referencing a method dynamically:

```
class Dog {
  def bark() { println "woof!" }
  def sit() { println "(sitting)" }
  def jump() { println "boing!" }
}

def doAction( animal, action ) {
  animal."$action"()                  //action name is passed at invocation
}

def rex = new Dog()

doAction( rex, "bark" )               //prints 'woof!'
doAction( rex, "jump" )               //prints 'boing!'
```

... But doing something like this doesn't work:

```
class Cat {
    def cat__PurrSound__List = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    def cat__MeowSound__List = [1, 2, 3]

    def someMethod(def sound) {
        assert sound == "PurrSound"

        def catSoundListStr = "cat__${obj.domainClass.name}__List"
        assert catSoundListStr = "cat__PurrSound__List"

        def catSoundList = "$catSoundListStr"
        assert catSoundList == cat__PurrSound__List // fail
    }
}
```

Comment: `assert foo."$someMethod"() == "asdf"` won't work, as you don't have a var called `someMethod`

Comment: @tim_yates Seems to work fine in my Grails test. I used it like the example [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy) that uses `$action`.

Comment: What is driving to use `"$foo"` instead of `foo`?

Comment: @dmahapatro Sorry, I botched the question.  As tim_yates said it doesn't work as advertised. I will corrected it. To be clear all I wanted to do was access a variable in a service based on a string that equaled that variables name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, so you can do:

```
def methodName = 'someMethod'
assert foo."$methodName"() == "asdf" // This works
```

and to get the object by name, you can do (in a Script at least):

```
// Cannot use `def` in a groovy-script when trying to do this
foo  = new Foo()

def objectName = 'foo'
assert this."$objectName".someMethod() == "asdf"
```

Comment: Awesome. Works in Grails too.

Comment: @dmahapatro What are you running it in?  It very much depends on the context, as to whether the object will be found in `this`

Comment: Same way OP has asked. This time I saved the script say `BarScript.groovy`. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6059220/)

Comment: @dmahapatro Oh yeah, **because** this is a Script, you have to remove the `def` from `def foo = new Foo()` to get it to work in a Script. Sorry about that...

Comment: Correct, its tricky, negligence prone (for me at least). But I still do not understand the rationale behind using `"$foo"` instead of using `foo` directly. Asked OP about it. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro I think the question is a bit messed up, and they meant `"$variableContainingTheStringFoo"` The original question doesn't work as advertised (see my comment above)